# Цели Google Analytics, Universal Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, javascript

Создал цель:

[image]

Добавил код для неё в js:

```
ga('send', 'event', 'cont', 'vopros');
```

Но цель не срабатывает, может, не в том порядке? Весь гугл перерыл, но порядок не описан нигде.

Answer (score 1):

В действии вам нужно указать — vopros.

Порядок перечисления в коде — category, action, label (strings), value (число), interaction (true/false)

Answer (score 0):

разные event action: в одном form3, в другом vopros